# Why is this throwing a IndexError?

Tags: python, loops, winapi, pyautogui, index-error

Disclaimer: I don't know exactly what would happen if you were to run the code since I've made some changes to it.

It doesn't matter what the code does but for those curious: It automates pixel art painting games where squares are marked by numbers and you click on them with the corresponding color. That's not exactly what this code does but it doesn't matter.

**The error:** [image]

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import win32api, win32con

white = (198, 198, 196)
blue = (125, 149, 199)

x1, y1, width, height = 10, 20, 1029, 798

x2 = x1 + width
y2 = y1 + height

while True:
    s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1, y1, width, height))
    for x in range(x1, x2):
        for y in range(y1, y2):
            if s.getpixel((x, y)) == blue:
                s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1, y1, width, height))
                win32api.SetCursorPos((range(x1, x2), range(y1, y2)))
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
                time.sleep(0.01)
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
                s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1, y1, width, height))
            if s.getpixel((x, y)) == white:
                s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1, y1, width, height))
                win32api.SetCursorPos((range(x1, x2), range(y1, y2)))
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN,0,0)
                time.sleep(0.01)
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP,0,0)
                time.sleep(0.01)
                s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1, y1, width, height))
            elif s.getpixel((x, y)) != white and s.getpixel((x, y)) != blue:
                break
            else:
                continue
```

Comment: It's preferable to post the error as text instead of an image, so people using screen readers can read it.

Comment: I expect that pixel indexes in the screenshot go from `0` to `width` and `height`, they don't have the same indexes as in the original screen.

Comment: You could print out x and y just before that if statement to see exactly when this is happening during execution (only once, or every time), but it is most likely what @Barmar is suggesting because Python is a zero-indexed language. If that is the case, then it should be solved by subtracting 1 from the values of x and y before you use them to retrieve pixels. Or, you can catch the IndexError at the end.

Comment: Your `else:` can never be reached, since the last `elif` condition matches anything where the first two conditions aren't matched. So the loop will always stop when it gets to the first pixel that isn't white or blue.

Comment: It's also not necessary to write `else: continue`. Loops continue automatically unless you break out of them.

Comment: What's with all those `sleep()` calls? I cannot imagine they do anything meaningful. To simulate bulk input you should also be using [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pixel indexes in the screenshot image start from `0`, not `x1` and `y1`. So you need to subtract them from your indexes.

```
while True:
    s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1, y1, width, height))
    for x in range(x1, x2):
        for y in range(y1, y2):
            curpixel = s.getpixel((x - x1, y - y1))
            if curpixel == blue:
                s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1, y1, width, height))
                win32api.SetCursorPos((range(x1, x2), range(y1, y2)))
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
                time.sleep(0.01)
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
                s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1, y1, width, height))
            if curpixel == white:
                s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1, y1, width, height))
                win32api.SetCursorPos((range(x1, x2), range(y1, y2)))
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN,0,0)
                time.sleep(0.01)
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP,0,0)
                time.sleep(0.01)
                s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1, y1, width, height))
            elif scurpixel != white and curpixel != blue:
                break
            else:
                continue
```